# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with Linux not working

Tags: java, linux, terminal

So, I've been developing an application in Java, for Windows, Linux and Mac. It uses commandline applications to compress/decompress some data, and as I try to make it work with wine, I cant seem to have any luck, neither have I found any questions solving the issues I have. This is how I call the commandline:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();
```

`command` is the string that is the completed command. Here is few things I've tried:

```
wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument"
/bin/bash -c wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument"
/bin/bash -c "wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument""
startx wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument"
startx /bin/bash -c wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument"
xterm -e wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument"
xterm -e /bin/bash -c wine "/path/to/executable" "/path/to/argument"
```

All of the above (aside from startx) do work on the Terminal of Linux, and none do with Java. At this point, I am pretty clueless as to what to do. I cant figure this out at all, and am just confused. I am not very familiar with Linux either, so it just adds more confusion. Just for reference, here is example of what I'd use to try to run first example command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wine \"/path/to/executable\" \"/path/to/argument\"").waitFor();
```

EDIT: I found out my issue is using quotation marks, removing them allowed me to use most above commands, however I also need to ensure that paths with spaces are supported. Any ideas?
I also switched to using `ProcessBuilder`, and made a custom parser to fit my needs.

Comment: **Why** are you trying to use `wine` (an emulator for Windows programs)?

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` of `Process`, separate each command/parameter into it's own `String` entry

Comment: too many layers of why...

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it work for you,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wine"+" /path/to/executable"+" /path/to/argument").waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You also might try:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh" + "-c" + "wine \"/path/to/executable\" \"/path/to/argument\"").waitFor();`